# Sub queries, Aliases and Stored Values- MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery, alias

I am given a problem as following:

Create a SQL statement that shows all shipped orders with a total of more than $14,000. The results must contain the customer's first_name, last_name, order_id, order shipped_date, number of items and total amount. Make sure any discount is taken into account when calculating the total amount.

Tables to draw from are:
Order Items: quantity, list_price, discount, order_id

Order: order_id, shipped_date, order_status, customer_id

Customers: first_name, last_name, customer_id.

I'm pretty new to SQL and sub-queries so I tried to build it from inside out and it kept giving me rows returned...until the last join ("sub2"). My code is below (inelegant, but I do need to figure out the problem before worrying about that).

```
select c.first_name, c.last_name, sub2.order_id, sub2.shipped_date, sub2.quantity, sub2.total_amount from customers AS c
    INNER JOIN(
            select o.order_id,  o.shipped_date, o.order_status, o.customer_id, sub1.total_price FROM orders as o
                INNER JOIN  (
                            SELECT oi.order_id, SUM((oi.list_price * oi.quantity) - ((oi.list_price * oi.quantity) * (oi.discount))) AS total_price 
                                FROM order_items AS oi
                                group by oi.order_id
                            ) AS sub1
                ON o.order_id = sub1.order_id
                WHERE
                    sub1.total_price > 14000
                            AND
                    o.order_status = 4
                    ) AS sub2
ON c.customer_id = sub2.customer_id
;
```

The error I'm getting is "Unknown column 'sub2.quantity' in 'field list'"
I imagine Mysql does not like this double nesting, so how can I go about solving this?

Comment: Surely (quantity * (x-y)) is easier to read (assuming discount is a fixed amount as opposed to a percentage)

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with nested queries, your problem is that the names on your nested statements don't correlate with the ones used outside as the alias.

eg: `... INNER JOIN(select o.order_id,  o.shipped_date, o.order_status, o.customer_id, sub1.total_price FROM ...`

doesn't has a `quantity` casted, so when it's rows are called outside as `sub2` there is an `Unknown column 'sub2.quantity' in field list`, it will fail also with `sub2.total_amount` for the same reason.

I'm guessing that since you are grouping by the total amount of an order, it should also give the sum of the items quantities. So the SQL should be like so:

```
select c.first_name, c.last_name, sub2.order_id, sub2.shipped_date, sub2.quantities, sub2.total_amount from customers AS c
    INNER JOIN(
            select o.order_id,  o.shipped_date, o.order_status, o.customer_id, sub1.total_price as total_amount, sub1.total_quantities FROM orders as o
                INNER JOIN  (
                            SELECT oi.order_id,SUM(oi.quantity) as total_quantities, SUM((oi.list_price * oi.quantity) - ((oi.list_price * oi.quantity) * (oi.discount))) AS total_price 
                                FROM order_items AS oi
                                group by oi.order_id
                            ) AS sub1
                ON o.order_id = sub1.order_id
                WHERE
                    sub1.total_price > 14000
                            AND
                    o.order_status = 4
                    ) AS sub2
ON c.customer_id = sub2.customer_id group by sub2.order_id;
```

Comment: There's a lot of query here. Just sayin'